# Why is Sunday always -1?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is the code:

```
-(int)getSystemDay
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger day = [components weekday];
    int weekday = (int) day;
    return weekday;
}
```

As I know, int for Sunday is always 1 but in my case when I print out `weekday`, it gives -1. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the `NSCalendarUnitWeekday` component, so the value is not retrieved.
An unspecified date component is -1 in Objective-C.

If you need only one component there is a more convenient way:

```
-(NSInteger)getSystemDay
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    return [gregorian component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```